# Run a c++ method from JavaScript (QTWebkit)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I can inject JavaScript to qtwebkit like this:

```
view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript();
```

But is it a way to do the inverted process? **Runnin a C++ Method from JavaScript?**

I thought about parsing the `*js` files with C++ and include some prefixed calls in the javascript to detect calls.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: sure is [node.js](http://nodejs.org) up in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is great built-in ability in Qt to integrate C++ and Javascript code. It is easily possible to make `QObject` available in script engine.

Just take a look at [Making Application Scriptable](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/scripting.html).